# Jensen's inequality with expectation of log and determinant

Tags: logarithms, determinant, jensen-inequality

I have a question when I try to have some analysis on the following expression.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\log_2\det\left(\mathbf{I}_L+\mathbf{X}\right)\right],
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation, $\log_2$ denotes the log function based on 2, $\det$ denotes the determinant operation, $\mathbf{I}_L$ is a identity matrix of size $L\times L$, and $\mathbf{X}$ is a non-diagonal matrix of size $L\times L$. My question is can I have the following inequality based on Jensen's inequality?
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\log_2\det\left(\mathbf{I}_L+\mathbf{X}\right)\right]\le\log_2\det\left(\mathbf{I}_L+\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{X}\right]\right)
\end{align}
I know it is true if there is no det operation, but no sure the case with det.

Comment: yes, this follows by concavity of log determinant on psd matrices.

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw thank you for the answer and the information. I really appreciate it!